# Conditional Heatmap in R ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to create a heatmap in ggplot based on a condition with this dataset. The dataset records rankings of 4 players over a period of time.

```
       Player 1  Player 2  Player 3  Player 4
1        3          1           4       2
2        3          4           2       1
3        2          3           4       1
4        4          2           1       3          
5        1          4           3       2
```

If a player places higher in row n+1, I would like the color to be green. If a player places lower in row n+1, I would like the color to be red. If they place the same, then I would like the color to be gray.

For example, player 1 placed the same in row 2 as he did in row 1, so I would like the color in row 2 column 1 to be gray. Player 4 placed higher in row 2 than he did in row 1, so I would like the color in row 2 column 4 to be green.

How can I achieve this in ggplot?

Comment: I would try a table library like kable :https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html

Answer (score 2):

Reshape your data into long format, add a `Week` column, calculate the `sign` of the `diff` of the score and use that for the fill:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Player", values_to = "Score") %>%
  group_by(Player) %>%
  mutate(Change = factor(c(0, sign(diff(Score)))),
         Week = factor(seq_along(Change), rev(seq_along(Change)))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Player, Week, fill = Change)) +
  geom_tile(color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Score), color = "white", size = 8) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red3", "gray30", "green4")) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.title.x.top = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

Or for a paler version,

```r
df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Player", values_to = "Score") %>%
  group_by(Player) %>%
  mutate(Change = factor(c(0, sign(diff(Score)))),
         Week = factor(seq_along(Change), rev(seq_along(Change)))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Player, Week, fill = Change)) +
  geom_tile(color = "black") +
  geom_text(aes(label = Score), size = 8) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#F06675", "gray90", "#86E075")) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16) +
  theme(axis.title.x.top = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```r
# your data:
df <- structure(list(Year = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), `Player 1` = c(3, 3, 
2, 4, 1), `Player 2` = c(1, 4, 3, 2, 4), `Player 3` = c(4, 2, 
4, 1, 3), `Player 4` = c(2, 1, 1, 3, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -5L
), class = "data.frame")

# solution:
library(tidyverse)
change_long <- df %>% mutate(across(starts_with("Player"), ~ sign(. - lag(.)))) %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("Player"), names_to = "Player", values_to = "Change") %>%
  drop_na()

ggplot(change_long, aes(Year, Player, fill = factor(Change))) +
  geom_tile() + scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "grey", "green"))
```